# what is the difference between ~ing and which is?

Tags: adjectives

I hope to understand the difference between the following phrases in bold:

Public outrage over **David Dao being** forcibly removed from flight strengthens potential lawsuit on personal injury or contract claims

Public outrage over **David Dao who was** forcibly removed from flight strengthens potential lawsuit on personal injury or contract claims

To me, I cannot tell which one is better. Could you explain the difference here?

Thank you so much.

Comment: The title doesn't really reflect the content. Where is the **which is** in the question body? Did you mean **who was**?

Answer (score 3):

“David Dao[’s] being forcibly removed…” means that the outrage was over the *removal*. That is, it’s the same as “public outrage over the forcible removal of David Dao”.

“David Dao[,] who was forcibly removed…” would mean that the outrage was over *Mr. Dao*. It still makes *some* sense: people could be outraged over “Mr. Dao” in the metaphorical sense of “the case of Mr. Dao”, but it’s somewhat awkward.

I would use *being*.